# Measuring single-ended signals with a high-speed ADC

Tags: adc

I want to measure two single-ended signals that go from 0V to 2V (they are separate signals, not differential). The signal can be DC or AC. One requirement is that the sampling rate should be as high as 20MSPS in some scenarios. The minimum resolution is 12-bit.

I was thinking of using the LTC2297, but I would then need to add a bias of minimum 0.5V according to the datasheet to be able to measure this signal. (So instead of 0V to 2V it would go from 0.5V to 2.5V).

I have found AD9201 which doesn't require the offset, but does not have enough resolution.

Any idea what device I could use? Or If I missed something in the datasheet of LTC2297 that would allow be to use it without an offset? Thanks!

Comment: I feel like adding an offset is the least of your problems; you need anti-alias filtering anyways, so adding a series capacitor and biasing around a positive voltage is not a big step. Also, if you're actually measuring AC signals, that would be a necessity either way. So, what's the problem with that?

Comment: It is called "signal conditioning" the operation thay allows a signal to be adapted to the input of a system. In your case it is sufficient to use an operational amplifier configured as a non inverting adder with two inputs, one for the signal and the other at a 0.5V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of ADC datasheets actually include reference circuits specifically to solve this problem.  Ti for example likes to recommend its own products for signal conditioning, and gives full designs you can use in some of their datasheets:

[image]

Taken from: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc12dl080.pdf

**Edit**:  *I noticed that the calculation for the terminating resistor in that datasheet example is incorrect.  The datasheet authors seem to assume that the 255 ohm resistor doesn't carry current, which is wrong.  Using the design equations in the LMH6550 datasheet, the correct value for the 49.9 1% resistor is actually 57.3 ohms since it is in parallel with the opamp input impedance.  The example would actually give a termination of 44 ohms.  Minor, but always double check the examples in datasheets!*

This particular amplifier has three inputs, +, - and a common mode voltage provided by the ADC.  It works like a normal amplifier, except it brings the output to the common mode voltage automatically:

[image]

Taken from:  https://www.ti.com/product/LMH6550

As a result, you feed in a waveform centered zero or some other voltage and it will shift it to whatever voltage the ADC expects.  Note that in your case you will need a negative supply rail for the opamp, although this can be easily generated since you need very little current.

While this is a reasonable part, TI, AD and others make lots of ADC drivers, some of which may be even better for your needs, so take a look through the catalogs. 20 MPSP is pretty slow, you may be able to get away with a cheaper part.